# Переменная в запросе SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Есть такой код с БД, нужен поиск через переменную по совпадению цифр в номере. В общем через LIKE, если вписать часть номера ничего не выдает, только если вписывать номер целиком.

```
def get_num(num):
    with sqlite3.connect("BasePers.db") as con:
        db = con.cursor()
        allnum = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM persons WHERE PersonNumber LIKE '{num}'").fetchall()
        return allnum

print(get_num(4515))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю как именно в `sqlite`, но обычно в `SQL` модификатор `LIKE` для поиска подстроки выглядит так:

```
LIKE '%что-то_что-мы-ищем%'
```

Где `%` означает маску для любых символов. Без `%` будет происходить поиск точного совпадения.

Comment: Хоспади как все просто оказыается, спасибо помогло подстановка %

Comment: @Banki не забывайте принимать ответы на свои вопросы, если они являются решениями. Для этого поставьте галку слева от нужного ответа